# How to do SEO for a one page web application?

Tags: seo, google, web-applications

I have created a web application. It lets you [search facebook update with keywords](http://www.fbstatussearch.com) at run time. How can I do SEO for it?

- There is just one page so its difficult to get ranking.
- Who ever I disscussed with, told me that you can not do SEO of such a
  website, you will have to market it on the social media. If so, how
  do websites like Google Search Engine, LinkedIn and many others made
  their way to get traffic from Google?

Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you shouldn't expect much.

The only thing I can imagine that could potentially get you some results would be backlink building (social media included). If people find the service useful they will promote/share it themselves as well.

Marginal improvements specific to your website would also be:

- change the *facebook status search* from `<h2>` to `<h1>`
- add `<meta>` keywords
- add `<meta>` distribution

As far as the second question goes (LinkedIn etc.), I cannot really tell, but certainly the huge amount of backlinks to those websites adds to their pagerank.